# Matlab : Help in finding minimum distance

Tags: matlab, distance

I am trying to find the point that is at a minimum distance from the candidate set. Z is a matrix where the rows are the dimension and columns indicate points. Computing the inter-point distances, and then recording the point with minimum distance and its distance as well. Below is the code snippet. The code works fine for a small dimension and small set of points. But, it takes a long time for large data set (N = 1 million data points and dimension is also high). Is there an efficient way?

Comment: If you have enough memory and the necessary toolbox, take a look at [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

Comment: Looking at the documentation I linked to, it seems the output from `pdist` will be an `[N, N-1]`-sized matrix: each point's distance with respect to every other point. You simply need to find the minimum of this matrix for each row. In other words, `min(pdist(Z,'euclidean'),[],2)` should be the minimal nearest-neighbour distance for each point, and `sum()`ming this gives you what you need. Of course you need to check this to your proper implementation, but it should be very straightforward.

Comment: It's a vector because you missed the last part of my comment: you need to use `sum()` on that vector to sum it up.....

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. The problem was that we need to call `squareform()` to get a proper matrix output from `pdist`, and then we also have to handle the diagonal of the matrix to avoid finding the 0 distance of each point from itself. There's also a necessary transposition involved for `pdist` to work. The problem is non-trivial enough that I did add an answer, please see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) to do the heavy lifting for you. This function will compute the pairwise distance between every two points in your array. The resulting vector has to be put into matrix form using [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) in order to find the minimal value for each pair:

```
N = 100;
Z = rand(2,N);  % each column is a 2-dimensional point

% pdist assumes that the second index corresponds to dimensions
% so we need to transpose inside pdist()
distmatrix = squareform(pdist(Z.','euclidean')); % output is [N, N] in size
% set diagonal values to infinity to avoid getting 0 self-distance as minimum
distmatrix = distmatrix + diag(inf(1,size(distmatrix,1)));
mindists = min(distmatrix,[],2); % find the minimum for each row
sum_dist = sum(mindists); % sum of minimal distance between each pair of points
```

This computes every pair *twice*, but I think this is true for your original implementation.

The idea is that `pdist` computes the pairwise distance between the columns of its input. So we put the transpose of `Z` into `pdist`. Since the full output is always a square matrix with zero diagonal, `pdist` is implemented such that it only returns the values above the diagonal, in a vector. So a call to `squareform` is needed to get the proper distance matrix. Then, the row-wise minimum of this matrix have to be found, but first we have to exclude the zero in the diagonals. I was lazy so I put `inf` into the diagonals, to make sure that the minimum is elsewhere. In the end we just have to sum up the minimal distances.

Comment: @SrishtiM although it sounds interesting, unfortunately I don't know anything about that subject, so I can't help you:)